# Please tell me how to print space in a file after stream pipe works completely in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a simple code which creates a readable stream and pipes it to a writeable stream and count spaces in the file.
My logic seems to be right.The problem is that before calculating space it goes to printing it.

```
var fs=require('fs');
var inStream=fs.createReadStream('data.txt');
var outStream=fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');
var printStream=process.stdout;
var space=0;
var upperStream=new Transform({
    transform(chunck,enc,cb){
        var text=chunck.toString().toUpperCase();
        for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
            if(text[i]==' ')
                space++;
        this.push(text);
        cb();
    }
});
inStream.pipe(upperStream).pipe(printStream);
console.log("Number of space in file : ",space);
```

data.txt contains 'Standard error'

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code to count spaces is async code. You should handle the instream `end` event. The end event will be emitted when data is read completely from instream. Once the space counting is done and data is written to printstream, and consumed fully from instream then only you will be able to get the actual space count.

Also you have missed requiring the Transform stream.

```
var { Transform } = require('stream');
var fs=require('fs');
var inStream=fs.createReadStream('data.txt');
var outStream=fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');
var printStream=process.stdout;
var space=0;
var upperStream=new Transform({
    transform(chunck,enc,cb){
        var text=chunck.toString().toUpperCase();
        for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
            if(text[i]==' ')
                space++;
        this.push(text);
        cb();
    }
});
inStream.pipe(upperStream).pipe(printStream);

inStream.on('end', () => console.log(`Number of space in file : ${space}`));
```

Read more about stream events here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: finish event works fine on upperStream and outStream but not on printStream

Comment: Yes, updated the answer. Actually in node, process.stdout is not like normal node streams so no finish or end event is there.